# Change the data type of a table column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I need to change the data type of a column from nvarchar(50) to nvarchar(MAX).  The problem is I already have data in hundreds of rows in this table and I don't want to lose the data.

Is there anyway to change the data type of a column without losing the data in that column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I preserve data when changing column datatypes in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547888/how-do-i-preserve-data-when-changing-column-datatypes-in-mysql)

Comment: @Li0liQ: not a duplicate - this question is about **SQL Server** (not MySQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - just change it!

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

This will take some time on a large table with data - but it's definitely **not** going to destroy any data! After all, you're only **extending** the size of the column.

**OF COURSE:** always do this **first** on a test/dev database, and **NEVER** do this without having a proper backup in place first!

Comment: Thanks!  Wanted to make sure before I altered the table.